# Mongo doesn't restore user password

Tags: mongodb, backup, restore

I have following scenario:

1. Dump Mongo database (cmd mongodump)
2. Change password from one of admin users
3. Restore Mongo database (cmd mongorestore)

**EDIT:**

I use following command for db dump:

```
mongodump -h $HOST:$PORT --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --authenticationDatabase $authdb -u $user -p $pass --gzip --archive=$destination
```

As a result password was not restored. Is there any defect plan that can be followed in mongodb for this specific case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found solution, --drop shoud be added in the command:

```
mongodump -h $HOST:$PORT --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --authenticationDatabase $authdb -u $user -p $pass --drop --gzip --archive=$destination
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your admin user is created in the database you dump?

The [authentication database](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#user-authentication-database) is not necessarily the used database in mongodb. If you want to dump/restore users, you have to dump/restore your authentication database(s).

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question. My admin user is created in admin db which I use as the authentication database. Interesting fact is that deleted users are restored, therefore I would say that with that command admin db is also dumped.